# Let me change my close vote, after the question was significantly edited?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, retracted-close-votes

I'm aware of the ["How do I change a close vote to a duplicate?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193654/how-do-i-change-a-close-vote-to-a-duplicate) question from a few years back, but mine's slightly different

A user asked a question, which wasn't clear. I left a comment explaining what information we needed, and left a close vote for *unclear what you're asking*. Some time later, the OP came back, and edited their question with the missing information. With that information in the question, it was then clear it was a duplicate. So, I retracted my unclear close vote, and went to close as a duplicate, but it wouldn't let me!

I can understand that there's a desire for stopping people changing their mind on a close vote when the question is unchanged, as covered in the older meta question. However, I can't see why I shouldn't be able to change my close vote after the OP makes significant changes via a big edit to there question

Could it be changed so that you can change your close vote (eg unclear to duplicate) after major edits to the question?

Comment: Tip: don't use "Why..." for feature requests. It is highly misleading.